# Why does 40000000000000000 - 3 = 40000000000000000 in Javascript

Tags: javascript

The title says it all why does `40000000000000000 - 3 = 40000000000000000` in JavaScript? The correct answer should be `39999999999999997`

Comment: It is probably using floating point numbers

Comment: Is that approximation not good enough for your purposes? It's like 99.99999999999997% correct, you need more precision? :)

Comment: @connexo unit testing my ethereum contract! 40000000000000000 wei === 0.04 ether. 40000000000000000 - 3 should break one of my tests, but wasn't! The reason being its the same number after subtracting 3. TIL

Comment: @connexo, i have a calculator.It's best for you to learn how to work with it

Comment: The duplicated post mark by @trincot is incorrect, realseanp needs to know why it does not work, not how to perform the calculation.

Comment: @e-info128, I quote the first line of the accepted answer: *"Because numbers in JavaScript are floating-point. They have limited precision."*.